# How to use an API in asp.net core and javascript

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, wavesurfer.js

I'm working on a web application with ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework Core Wavesurferjs API.

I successfully created the CRUD of my application and it's working just fine,
but in my Home Index view, I'm using an API with javascript in order to use this API's features, and as it says i have to write a javascript code inside my web app in order to make it run as the following :

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = '@Model.MusicList';
    console.log(path);
        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '#waveform',
            waveColor: 'violet',
            progressColor: 'purple'
        });
            wavesurfer.load(path);
            wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
            wavesurfer.play();
        });
</script>
}
```

As you can see i'm using this line of code :

> @Model.MusicList

it's the paramatere i'm passing through the razor page from the controller as following :

Razor View :

```
@model MusicSurfer.ViewModal.HomeViewModel.HomeViewModel
```

Controller :

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "music");
        var model = new HomeViewModel()
        {
            MusicList = path
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

In order to make the API working, i need to load the file .mp3 which is stored in the music folder in the ***wwwrooot*** directory by passing its path in the ***.load()*** function.
But it appears that the path is not passed correctly as follows :
[image]

How can i solve this problem please ? 
Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: `_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` provides an absolute file-path, but it seems like a relative URL would work for your purposes. Try it with `string path = Url.Content("~/music/file.mp3")` or similar.

Comment: To achieve your requirement, 1) in controller action, please set `MusicList` with something like this `var model = new HomeViewModel{ MusicList = "~/music/file.mp3" };` 2) in your view page, as @KirkLarkin mentioned, please use `var path = '@Url.Content(Model.MusicList)';`